# Protocol/Delegate function doesn't trigger (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

The function in `ViewController` doesn't print anything. Tried re-writing the code several times with no success. Do you guys have any suggestions?

Code:

```
protocol CustomSegmentedControlDelegate:class {
    func change(to index:Int)
}

class CustomSegmentedControl: UIView {

weak var delegate:CustomSegmentedControlDelegate?

@objc func buttonAction(sender:UIButton) {
        for (buttonIndex, btn) in buttons.enumerated() {
            btn.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)
            if btn == sender {
                let selectorPosition = frame.width/CGFloat(buttonTitles.count) * CGFloat(buttonIndex)
                selectedIndex = buttonIndex
                delegate?.change(to: selectedIndex)
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    self.selectorView.frame.origin.x = selectorPosition
                }
                btn.setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now the main ViewController code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CustomSegmentedControlDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var interfaceSegmented: CustomSegmentedControl!{
        didSet{
            interfaceSegmented.setButtonTitles(buttonTitles: ["OFF","HTTP","AUTO"])
            interfaceSegmented.selectorViewColor = .orange
            interfaceSegmented.selectorTextColor = .orange
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    func change(to index: Int) {
        print("segmentedControl index changed to \(index)")
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't set the delegate?

Comment: How exactly should I set it, maybe I set it false, but it always gave me an error in the view did load @Sweeper

Comment: This question solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41007529/sending-data-to-uiviewcontroller-from-uiview-subclass-with-delegate